# Sending multiple attachment in an email using PHP

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I have problem sending an email with multiple attachments. Here is the code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['sendEmail']))
    {

        foreach($_FILES['uploadEmail']['error'] as $key=>$value){
            if(!$_FILES['uploadEmail']['error'][$key]){
                $target_path = "";
                $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadEmail']['name'][$key]); 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadEmail']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path)){
                    $files[] = $_FILES['uploadEmail']['name'][$key];
                }
            }
        }

        $toEmails = explode(",",$_POST['toEmail']);
        $count = count($toEmails);
        $i = 0;    $j = 1;    $k = 100;
        $bcc = '';
        while($i<$count){
            $bcc .= $toEmails[$i].",";
            if($j==$k || $i==$count-1){
                $j=1;
                //echo $bcc.'<br />'.$sub.'<br />'.$message.'<br /><br />';
                $from = 'test@gmail.com';
                $sub = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];

                /////////////////////////
                $headers = 'From:'. $from . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Bcc:". $bcc . "\r\n";


                // boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

                // headers for attachment 
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

                // multipart boundary 
                $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

                // preparing attachments
                for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
                    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
                    //echo "<br>".filesize($files[$x]);
                    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
                    fclose($file);
                    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                }

                    // send
                    /////////////////////////

                mail('',$sub,$message,$headers);
                $bcc = '';
            }else{
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        new nicEditor().panelInstance('message');
       // new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area2');
  });</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr><td><label for="toEmail">Send To : </label></td><td><textarea id="toEmail" name="toEmail" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="subject">Subject : </label></td><td><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="98"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="toEmail">Message : </label></td><td><textarea id="message" name="message" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="upload[]">Attachments:</label></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>1</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>2</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>3</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>4</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>5</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>6</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>7</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>8</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>9</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>10</label></td><td><input type="file" name="uploadEmail[]"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="sendEmail" id="sendEmail"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

I received mail but could not find any attachments with it.
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Here is an email body which I got in mail:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x2d454346f03d2c19cfefc838ce4d8623x"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_x2d454346f03d2c19cfefc838ce4d8623x Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ds fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf sffdfsdfsdfs fsdfdf sdf s

--==Multipart_Boundary_x2d454346f03d2c19cfefc838ce4d8623x Content-Type: {"application/octet-stream"};  name="/tmp/phpHFTvAw"
Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="Lighthouse.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64




--==Multipart_Boundary_x2d454346f03d2c19cfefc838ce4d8623x Content-Type: {"application/octet-stream"};  name="/tmp/phpyX67HR"
Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="Penguins.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64




--==Multipart_Boundary_x2d454346f03d2c19cfefc838ce4d8623x
```

Answer (score 4):

### Answer

There are a few problems with your code that I have detailed below.

- #### Line endings

  ```
    $headers = 'From:'. $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc:". $bcc . "\r\n";

    ...

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"
             .  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n"
             .  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n"
             . "--{$mime_boundary}\n"
             . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"
             . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n"
             . $message
             . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
  ```

  Lines in email messages are separated by `CRLF` (`\r\n`) sequences. It is unclear whether the `mail()` function converts `\n` into `\r\n` or not, but considering that your `From:` and `Bcc:` headers are using `\r\n`, these should probably use the same. Your output also indicates that the line endings are possibly missing or malformed.

  From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

  > If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably [» qmail](http://cr.yp.to/qmail.html)) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with [» RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822).
- #### Header syntax

  ```
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n"
             .  " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
  ```

  Remove the braces and the quotes:

  ```
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n"
             .  " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
  ```

  Also, the `name` parameter has been deprecated in favour of the `filename` parameter in the `Content-Disposition` header. If you want to keep it for some backward compatibility, you should remove the path from it. (Your output indicates that you're using `tmp_name` rather than `name`).
- #### Delimiters

  ```
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
      ...
      $message .= /* body part */;
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
  ```

  Note that the final delimiter must have two trailing dashes. Insert the dividing delimiters at the beginning of the loop, and add a close delimiter after the loop:

  ```
    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
      ...
      $message .= /* body part */;
    }

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
  ```

  See the section on Email syntax below.
- #### Line lengths

  ```
    $k = 100;
    ...
    while($i<$count){
      $bcc .= $toEmails[$i].",";
      if($j==$k || $i==$count-1){
        ...
        $headers .= "Bcc:". $bcc . "\r\n";
  ```

  Note that there are line length limits in email messages. [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1.1):

  > ```
  >    ...                    Each line of characters MUST be no more than
  >      998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding
  >      the CRLF.
  > ```

  You may want to cut your `Bcc`'s shorter or introduce [FWS (Folding White Space)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.2):

  ```
    $bcc .= $toEmails[$i].",\r\n ";  /* FWS */
  ```
- #### Other issues

  Some further issues or notices that might or might not be useful:

  ---

  ```
    foreach($_FILES['uploadEmail']['error'] as $key=>$value){
        if(!$_FILES['uploadEmail']['error'][$key]){
  ```

  The last line is the same as:

  ```
        if(!$value){
  ```

  ---

  ```
    $target_path = "";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadEmail']['name'][$key]);
  ```

  I'm assuming that `$target_path` should be initialized to an upload directory.

  ---

  ```
    $toEmails = explode(",",$_POST['toEmail']);
  ```

  Generally, you should not allow random users to provide outgoing email addresses, but I suspect that this is an internal application for trusted users.

---

### Email syntax

This is an excerpt of what the structure of a multi-part message body looks like according to RFC 2046. (BNF syntax, somewhat simplified.)

> ```
> multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
>                   dash-boundary CRLF
>                   body-part *encapsulation
>                   close-delimiter
>                   [CRLF epilogue]
> dash-boundary := "--" boundary
> body-part := MIME-part-headers [CRLF *OCTET]
> encapsulation := delimiter
> CRLF body-part
> delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary
> close-delimiter := delimiter "--"
> ```

### References

- <del>[RFC 2822 Internet Message Format](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)</del> (Obsoleted by RFC 5322)
- [RFC 5322 Internet Message Format](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)
- [RFC 2045 (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message Bodies](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)
- [RFC 2046 (MIME) Part Two: Media Types](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)

Answer (score 3):

I propose to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for sending mails with attachements:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';                      // If this file is not located in the same directory, use __DIR__ . "/path/to/PHPMailerAutoload.php"

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

?>
```

Download and documentation: [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: thanks for your answer but requirement is send email only using mail function not using phpmailer.