# php mail attachment - error - how to debug

Tags: php, email, csv, email-attachments

I search and try different methods to produce a php mail with an attachment, which is saveable with the Client (Outlook). It doesn't work porper and I don't know why?

If the script send the mail with this code:

```
    $result  = mail($mail_to, $subject, $headers);
```

I got an email with an inline base64 coded attachment and if use it in this way:

```
    $result  = mail($mail_to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

or

```
    $result  = mail($mail_to, $subject, $text, $headers);
```

I got the PHP Error: "false" - the mail could not send.

So it isn't and Mailserverproblem, I think and from headersview I think, it should work and I get no mail error on the Linux site.

A part from the mail coming with the attachment inline:

```
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    From: user@nowhere.xyz
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="F34A3E8D822EE5A70EEDE9C3C143243C"

    --F34A3E8D822EE5A70EEDE9C3C143243C
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="A0403290562B2A2F19FB62E48C51BE33"

    --A0403290562B2A2F19FB62E48C51BE33
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

    Hello Mr. Xyz,
    Some stupid text as an example.

    --A0403290562B2A2F19FB62E48C51BE33--

    --F34A3E8D822EE5A70EEDE9C3C143243C
    Content-Type: application/CSV; charset="ISO-8859-1"; name="trouble.csv"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="trouble.csv"

    ...
    YWNodW5nIG5pY2h0IGVyZm9yZGVybGljaCAvIG3DtmdsaWNoIjsiIjsiIjsK

    --F34A3E8D822EE5A70EEDE9C3C143243C--
```

The matching PHP code:

`$text     = "Hello Mr. Xyz," . $nl . "Some stupid text as an example." . $nl;
        $content  = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $nl;
        $headers .= "From: " . $mail_from . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary1 . "\"" . $nl . $nl;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1 . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" . $boundary2 . "\"" . $nl . $nl;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary2 . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain" . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $nl . $nl;
        $headers .= $text . $nl;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary2 . "--" . $nl . $nl;

        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1 . $nl . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/excel; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"; name=\"xyz.csv\"" . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $nl;
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"xyz.csv\"" . $nl . $nl;
        $headers .= $content . $nl;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1 . "--" . $nl;`

So, where is the bug? How can I debug such a Situation?
Thx in advance...

Comment: `§nl` is probably a syntax error. See also [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436) for typical causes of mail() failure. While the MIME [multipart assembling looks ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757772/sending-multiple-attachment-in-an-email-using-php) for once, you'd still be better of with [PHPMailer/SwiftMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303783/phpmailer-vs-swiftmailer) for such tasks. (Both provide better debugging options for SMTP errors in particular.)

Comment: The "§nl" would be a syntax error, but it is just a transfer bug from the orignal source to the post here.

Comment: The Trouble is...:

double nl in $eaders... removing them I got an email with an attachment, but it is too short and the message text is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works....

```
        $text     = "Hello Mr. Xyz," . $crnl . "Some stupid text as an example."                . $crnl;
        $content  = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0"                                                         . $crnl;
        $headers .= "From: " . $mail_from                                                       . $crnl;

        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary1 . "\""            . $nl . $crnl;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain"                                                  . $nl;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1                                                           . $crnl;
        $headers .= 'Content-Length: '.strlen($text)                                            . $crnl;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8-bit"                                          . $nl . $crnl;
        $headers .= $text;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1                                                           . $crnl;

        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/excel; charset=\"ISO8859-1\"; name=\"xyz.csv\""  . $nl . $crnl;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1                                                           . $crnl;
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"xyz.csv\""                     . $crnl;
        $headers .= 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($content)                                       . $crnl;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"                                         . $nl . $crnl;
        $headers .= $content;
        $headers .= "--" . $boundary1 . "--"
```

...with a small bug. I have an extra attment, but that's for now ok. We other thing is a longer play with "\n", "\r\n" and a mixture of both on the right places (lines).