# How to send mail with 2 attachments with different name in PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

I am working on a form where I have 2 input file fields with different name. I am using `mail()` function to send mail. But I am able to send only one attachment.

Please help me on how to send both attachments.

Here is my HTML code

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Upload Photograph:</label>
  <input type="file" name="uploadimage" value="" />
  <label>Upload File:</label>
  <input type="file" name="uploadfile" value="" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn_three" name="upload">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
        $fromemail = "abc@mail.com"
        $toemail = "xyz@mail.com";  
        $subject = "Subject";;
        $email_message .= "Please find the attachment";
        $headers = "From: ".$fromemail;
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        if($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]!= "")
        {  
            $strFilesName = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];  
            $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"])));  
            $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                              "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                              "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            $email_message .= "\n\n";
            $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                              "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;\n" .
                              " name=\"{$strFilesName}\"\n" .
                              "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                              " filename=\"{$strFilesName}\"\n" .
                              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
            $strContent .= "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
        }
        if(mail($toemail, $subject, $email_message, $headers))
        {
            ----
        }
        else
        {
            ----
        }
    }
    ?>
```

How to send one more file?

I have tried with the same code for one more file too, but it is not working

I also tried using the below code

```php
if($_FILES["uploadimage"]["name"]!= ""){  
    $strImageName = $_FILES["uploadimage"]["name"];  
    -----}
```

Please help!

Comment: Make sure you separate the 1st file from the 2nd file by another $mime_boundary

Comment: as i have less knowledge in php, can you tell me how to add one more mime boundary please @

Comment: Does this answer your question (pay attention to the part on delimiter) ? [Sending multiple attachment in an email using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757772/sending-multiple-attachment-in-an-email-using-php)

Comment: I indented your PHP code, as it was a mess without it.  From that exercise, I see your are missing a couple `;` when you set `$email_message`.  Fix this first.